# How do I add an object MemberList which contains a name and a list of names?

Tags: java, linked-list

Basically I want to create linked lists for people firstly when they sign up for a game. This is done by a method signUp(String name).Eg, John becomes a member when he has signed up.

The instance he becomes a member, and anyone else so I think I'd need lots of lists, I want to create a list for him for when he gets game invites. Eg, create a new linked list linkedList johnsGameInvites = new linkedList();. I also want to create another list linkedList johnsFriends = new linkedList();. This goes for anyone so say Sam would be samsGameInvites and samsFriends etc.

My code so far:

```
linkedList members = new linkedList();

//Method to sign people up
public boolean signUp(String name) {
    if(members.isInMyList(name)) {
        System.out.println("That name is already taken.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        members.addToMyList(name);
        System.out.println("That name will now be registered.");
        //NEW CODE//
        Person gameMember = new Person(name)
        return true;
    }
}

//Method to send game invite
public boolean sendGameInvite(String requester, String receiver) {
    //Checking if the two people are signed up
    if(!members.isInMyList(requester) || !members.isInMyList(receiver)) {
        System.out.println("One or both of these people are not signed up.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //NEW CODE//
        gameMember.addToMyList(requester);
        System.out.println("A request will now be sent to " + receiver + "'s account.");

        return true;
    }   
}
```

My next method I would do is to send friend requests between players.
Could anyone write some code to show me how to make a MemberList and then other lists involving the names of the people who sign up and then how to use them in the game invites and friend requests methods? I'm pretty sure I need to make a Member object that contains a name and then a list of names but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're here as a community to help debug existing code. Asking us to write code (vs edit or debug) for you isn't what SO is for though. Perhaps you can show us what you've tried so far in regards to your issue, and perhaps we can use that as a basis.

Comment: I don't know what to do so I've been reading around trying to find some ideas. I think I understand what to do now but I have no idea how to actually code it. I'm fairly new so I learn better with examples. I don't necessarily want someone to write my code for me, more that I want some example/help code to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a separate class to hold that information. For example:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    LinkedList<Invites> gameInvites; //replace "Invites" with whatever type of object you intend to fill this with
    LinkedList<Person> friends;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        gameInvites = new LinkedList<>();
        friends = new LinkedList<>();
    }
}
```

You could then include methods relevant to `Person` objects by including them in the `Person` class instead of the main class. In your main method, you can now create a `LinkedList<Person>` that will hold all the people and their info.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was wondering, in my signUp method I want to create a new instance if they sign up successfully. Under the line in my code "That name will now be registered." I have added a new line which consists of Person gameMember  = new Person(name);. Basically, how would I create new instances so it can be seen outside of the method because I need to create the instance in the method I think.

Comment: You can access them outisde the method by referencing their index in `members`.

Comment: So if I wanted to add a name to a specific person's list in another method, would it look something like gameMember.addToMyList(requester);? I just tried this example but it didn't compile. It said it couldn't find the symbol addToMyList. How could I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an `addToMyList` method?

Comment: Yes, it's in my LinkedList class I made. I used addToMyList in the method above which was signUp and it works as expected. I did some print statements to check and it's okay. I think the problem may be trying to add to the list gameMember because gameMember is created in the signUp method.

Comment: Can you update your original post to show the code you have now?

Comment: You need to pass `gameMember` to `sendGameInvite()`. You also need to create an `addToMyList()` method in the `Person` class.

Comment: When passing gameMember to sendGameInvite() it says an identifier is expected. I don't know what to put in there. I know I need sendGameInvite(String requester, String receiver) but I don't know what else to put in the brackets.

Comment: Try `sendGameInvite(String requester, String receiver, Person gameMember)`.

Comment: It compiles now. Thank you for the help. I'll try seeing if the method does what I want and reply back here if I have more problems.